# How Can I paste the content of a text file 400 times

Tags: text, paste

its for a unity research project, I dont want to have to press control v exactly 400 times. I just want to paste it in another .txt file
this is the text
http://pastebin.com/m1u4AFAr
Thank you for you help

Comment: Where do you want to paste it in Unity?

Comment: I just want to paste it in a bigger text file, dont worry about unity

Comment: **dont worry about unity** but you tagged Unity.... paste that text from that link 400 times into one text file?

Comment: I tagged it just in case there is a simple way to do it with unity but if I get the text file pasted with any other program its fine, as I then will import it into unity

Comment: you can achive that with any programming/scripting language (but I really don't see the purpose of having such a file). For example in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: it is a cell simulation where each column is a cell variable over time

Comment: ok Ill try to just create a loop in unity that should be fine thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Unity. Go to that link and copy the text. Run this script in Unity and it will duplicate the text for 400 times and save it. It will show you where it saved it. Any text you have in the clipboard will be duplicated 400 times.

```
void Start()
{
    //Get Clipboard
    string fileInfo = GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer;


    if (fileInfo == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clipboard is Empty. Exited");
        return; //exit
    }

    //Multiply by file 400
    System.Text.StringBuilder crazyfileX400 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
    {
        crazyfileX400.Append(fileInfo).Append("\r\n");
    }


    string filename = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "crazyFile.txt";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, crazyfileX400.ToString());

    Debug.Log("File written to " + filename);
}
```

Comment: thank you illl check it out now, ill run this script in any game object

Comment: @Kepazino I tried it and works great. Let me know is there is any problem.

Comment: I guess this works in c sharp outside unity as well?

Comment: No, unless you change the parts that uses Unity API. Remove `Application.persistentDataPath`, Replace `Debug.Log` with `Console.WriteLine`. Finally, replace `GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer` with `Clipboard.GetText`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this open source [macro-creation and automation software](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
You can use it to write a script that does the job for you. Here's a [a script](http://lifehacker.com/372457/copy-and-paste-without-switching-windows) for simple copy and paste:

```
#c::
Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}{ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}
sleep, 300
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}{ENTER}{ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}
return
```

You could adapt it to your situation by adding a loop.